# Third Party Vector Tile Source in Mapbox Studio

Tags: mapbox, vector-tiles, mapbox-studio

I am currently styling a map in Mapbox Studio (the web interface, not desktop application) and would like to add a layer that draws on vector tiles from a third party.

When I select "New Layer" and am presented with "No tileset, click to select" for the source data, and then select "New tileset" the only options are to upload a file or create from an existing dataset.

[image: New tileset dialogue]

Is there a way to add third party vector data in Mapbox Studio?

Comment: Have you found a solution by now?